# PHP To Select multiple rows of MYSQL database

Tags: mysql

I need some php code to pull from mysql database in Xampp.  I then need to transfer the values of no1 and no2 to javascript for calculations.  The mysql data is attached.  This program only selects the last row, however, I would like for it to go through all rows and show the new values of the variables no1 and no2.

I have this code below:

```
<[enter image description here][1]?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";



$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT s_num, movie, no1, no2 FROM table_1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "Name: " . $row["s_num"]. " Movie: " . $row["movie"]. $row["no1"].                

$row["no2"]. "<br>";

$no1 = $row['no1'];

$no2 = $row['no2'];

echo "Number 1 is $no1"; 
echo "Number 2 is $no2"; 

echo $no1 + $no2;
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var no_1 = <?php echo $no1 ?>; 
var no_2 = "<?php echo $no2 ?>"; 

alert (no_1);

alert ("The value is:"+no_1);

alert (no_2);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use `fetch_all()` function to fetch the result set into an array and iterate over it after:

```
//Copy result into a associative array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//Copy result into a numeric array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);

//Copy result into both a associative and numeric array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

so using the associative option your code would looks like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT s_num, movie, no1, no2 FROM table_1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var values = [];
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    foreach ($resultArray as $row){
        echo "values.push({no1: ".$row['no1'].", no2: ".$row['no2']."});";
    }
}

$conn->close();
?>
</script>
```

now you have your values in the javascript-array `values` you can iterate over it and get your values row for row

Comment: I am fairly new to mysql.  Which one would I need to use and where do I place it? Also, would it replace anything?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: btw. your last part of the code is not in the loop, so the variables `$no1` `$no2` will be set to the value of the last loop-iteration. Thats probably the reason, why you only get the values for the last row. I'm actually not sure what you are trying to do with the `<script>` part, so I'm not sure where to put it into the loop

Comment: Thanks a lot JohnnyAW.  What I am trying to do is to pull the values for no1 and no2 values from the database using PHP from each row.   I then want to transfer the values from PHP to Javascript.  Most of my formulas for calculations are in Javascript, so this is the reason why I want to do this.                                                                                        So it would pull no1 and then no2 values from row 1.  Then the formulas would execute in Javascript.  Next, it would pull the no1 and no2 values from row 2.  Then the formulas would execute in Javascript.

Comment: ok, I updated the answer. I didnt test it, so it may contain syntax errors

Comment: @Todd just for clarification: php-code will be executed on the server side before the browser will receive html including javascript. So it is not possible to execute php->javascript->php. It is also not possible to use variables from php in javascript, because at the time javascript will be executed php is gone. Thats why you need to create javascript-statements with values from php.

Comment: Is there a way to open the php file and assign values to no1 and no2 with a seperate web page containing javascript code?

Comment: I don't really understand the question